# Enviar e-mail com anexo em Lua

Tags: lua, envio-de-email

Estou a tentar enviar um e-mail atras do *socket*. Consigo enviar um e-mail, com anexo, mas quero também adicionar texto ao e-mail e não consigo. Exemplo do código:

```
local smtp = require("socket.smtp")
local mime = require("mime")
local ltn12 = require("ltn12")
rcpt = {
    "exemplo@exemplo.com"
    }

mesgt = {
  headers = {
    ["content-type"] = 'text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"',
    ["content-transfer-encoding"] = 'quoted-printable',
    to = "exepmo <"exemplo@exemplo.com">",
    ["content-type"] = 'image/png; name="image.png"',
    ["content-disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="image.png"',
    ["content-description"] = 'a beautiful image',
    ["content-transfer-encoding"] = "BASE64"
    subject = sujet
  },

   body = "texto texto texto",
      [1] = { 

      body = ltn12.source.chain(
            ltn12.source.file(io.open("image.png", "rb")),
            ltn12.filter.chain(
                mime.encode("base64"),
                mime.wrap()
            )
        )

        }
      }
   r, e = smtp.send{
      from = from,
      rcpt = rcpt, 
      source = smtp.message(mesgt),
      port = 21,    
      server = servidordemail
  }
```

O código funciona se enviar ou o texto ou o anexo. Se quiser enviar os dois não me funciona.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

A [documentação](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/smtp.html) que você usou na pergunta anterior mostra como deve fazer mas você está fazendo de um jeito diferente. Parte relevante:

```
  headers = {
     -- Remember that headers are *ignored* by smtp.send. 
     from = "Sicrano de Oliveira <sicrano@example.com>",
     to = "Fulano da Silva <fulano@example.com>",
     subject = "Here is a message with attachments"
  },
  body = {
    preamble = "If your client doesn't understand attachments, \r\n" ..
               "it will still display the preamble and the epilogue.\r\n" ..
               "Preamble will probably appear even in a MIME enabled client.",
    -- first part: no headers means plain text, us-ascii.
    -- The mime.eol low-level filter normalizes end-of-line markers.
    [1] = { 
      body = mime.eol(0, [[
        Lines in a message body should always end with CRLF. 
        The smtp module will *NOT* perform translation. However, the 
        send function *DOES* perform SMTP stuffing, whereas the message
        function does *NOT*.
      ]])
    },
    -- second part: headers describe content to be a png image, 
    -- sent under the base64 transfer content encoding.
    -- notice that nothing happens until the message is actually sent. 
    -- small chunks are loaded into memory right before transmission and 
    -- translation happens on the fly.
    [2] = { 
      headers = {
        ["content-type"] = 'image/png; name="image.png"',
        ["content-disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="image.png"',
        ["content-description"] = 'a beautiful image',
        ["content-transfer-encoding"] = "BASE64"
      },
      body = ltn12.source.chain(
        ltn12.source.file(io.open("image.png", "rb")),
        ltn12.filter.chain(
          mime.encode("base64"),
          mime.wrap()
        )
      )
    },
    epilogue = "This might also show up, but after the attachments"
  }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/SendMail2.lua).